# Angular pagination controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, controller, factory

I am applying for a job. I am a react developer and yet they saw my resume and sent me AngularJS questions. **Is this problem answerable or are they just jerking my chain?** Can any one direct me to resources where I can learn to answer this quesiton thanks.

Requirements:

Write a controller in AngularJS that uses the notifications service to fetch user's notifications. You should be able to return 10 notifications, fetch the following 10 using pagination, then continue until there are no more results.

Notification Parameters:
- offset: how many notifications to skip
- limit: how many notifications to return
- from: timestamp in milliseconds from when to begin, used for pagination so new notifications don't throw off results.

--------> factory service

```html
'use strict';

angular.module('app')

.factory('NotificationService', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/me/notifications/:controller', {
    id: '@_id'
  },
  {
    notifications: {
      method: 'GET'
    },
    getSettings: {
      method: 'GET',
      params: {
        controller: 'settings'
      }
    },
    setSettings: {
      method: 'POST',
      params: {
        controller: 'settings'
      }
    }
  });
});
```

--------> controller

```js
'use strict';

(function () {

  function NotificationController() {

  }

  angular.module('app').controller('NotificationController', NotificationController);

})();
```

Comment: Just ask google. Show us, what you have tried so far? People are not here to solve assignment for you, they could help if you stuck at some point or they can rather give better path to proceed.

Comment: I wasnt asking for someone to solve it. I was asking is it possible to be solved with the given information. I know nothing of angular (im a react dev) and was wondering if they are just jerking me around.

Comment: @ChristopherLin I think the question is pretty straight forward. They are asked a question to list down all the notifications(notifications could be in a database) and display  in a grid or some other control. But don't hard code any value for example number of records to pull on every pagination, offset etc. In future it may change. So your code should be very extensible. I think those things they might looking. Your code quality

Comment: @ChristopherLin Also angular services is nothing but to  write  reusable logic(could be database service or a piece of client side logic) and can pass to the component or controller as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks Jameel, I will learn angular over the weekend and answer the question.

Comment: So you feel the services file needs to be edited as well?

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping others could comment and lead me in the correct direction.
As of now I am not sure if I am supposed to alter the factory or not and assume the pagination will be done in the query. Any help thanks!

```js
(function () {
// assuming the current page, offset and limit are defined by the user settings
  function NotificationController($scope, $resource, NotificationService) {
    // declaring things i might need
    let notifications = NotificationService.notifications();
    let totalNotes = notifications.length;
    let id = $scope.id;
    let offset = $scope.offset;
    let startTime = $scope.starTime;
    let pageIterator = $scope.pageIterator;
    let pages = Math.ceil(totalNotes / pageIterator);

    // check if grabbed some undefined items from database
    function checkUndef(notes){
        let newNotes = notes;
        if (notes[notes.length - 1]=== undefined ){
            newNotes.pop();
            return checkUndef(newNotes);
        } else return newNotes;
    }
    // filterfor time
    function checkTime(note) {
       if( note.createAt > startTime) {
           return note;
       }
        )
    }
    // finally running the functions
    notifications = checkUndef(notes);
    notifications = notifications.filter(checkTime); 
    return notifications.slice($scope.offset, $scope.offset+$scope.pageIterator);
        
  }

  angular.module('app').controller('NotificationController', [$scope,$resource, NotificationController]);

})();
```